# SQL Count Non-Empty Cells in Row and Group by Ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in `main table`:

```
| id | Attendance              | Accountability          | Respect                    |   |
|----|-------------------------|-------------------------|----------------------------|---|
| 1  | John was always on time | John is accountable     | John is always respectful  |   |
| 2  | Ann never missed a day  | Ann is very accountable |                            |   |
| 3  |                         |                         | Dan was very disrespectful |   |
```

I need to count the number of non-empty cells for each row, then sort into  ranges.

**EXAMPLE:**

First count the non-empty cells.

```
| id | Non-empty |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | 3         | # Row 1 has 3 comments
| 2  | 2         | # Row 2 has 2 comments and 1 empty cell
| 3  | 1         | # Row 3 has 1 comment and 2 empty cells
```

> Let's call this result "Table A"

Then create a grouping based on ranges of comments left. **This is the final result.**

```
| id | Range        | Count |
|----|--------------|-------|
| 1  | 1-2 comments | 2     | # 2 rows have between 1 and 2 comments
| 2  | 3-4 comments | 1     | # 1 row has between 3 and 4 comments
| 3  | 5+ comments  | 0     | # 0 rows have more than 5 comments
```

> Let's call this result "Table B"

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

```
select 
  case 
    when Non-empty between 1 and 2 then '1-2 comments'
    when Non-empty between 3 and 4 then '3-4 comments'
    else then '5+ comments'
  end as `Range`,
 count(1) as `Count`
from `Table A`
group by `Range`
```

> This query should produce Table B from Table A

**WHAT I NEED**

A single SQL query that produces Table B from Main Table.

So, I guess I need a query that can produce Table A, then combine it with the above query.

If there's an easier way to get Table B from Main Table then I welcome it!

Comment: First: MySQL or SQL Server? Second: I don't think there is something called `Cells` in both. Third: are you mean `empty` or `NULL`?

Comment: @Sami 1: SQL Server 2: `Cells` is Excell speak for `Fields` (I think) 3: I do mean empty (as in `""`) as opposed to `NULL`

Comment: Well, there is no `Fields` too :). There is `Columns` and `Rows`.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server!!!!  Remove tag that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final query which worked for me.

Thank you @flip! Your answer got me the closest.

```
SELECT
    case 
        when comments between 1 and 2 then '1-2 comments'
        when comments between 3 and 4 then '3-4 comments'
        else '5+ comments'
    end as `Range`,
    count(1) as `Count` 
FROM( 
    SELECT id, 
        SUM(IF(Respect != '', 1, 0)) +
        SUM(IF(Accountability != '', 1, 0)) + 
        SUM(IF(Attendance != '', 1, 0))
    FROM `main table` 
    GROUP BY id
)AS T GROUP BY `Range`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Total BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN '1-2 Comments'
        WHEN Total BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN '3-4 Comments'
        WHEN Total >= 5 THEN '5+ Comments'
    END AS Range,
    COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        SUM(CASE Attendance WHEN LENGTH(Attendence) > 0 OR Attendence IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) + SUM(CASE Accountability WHEN LENGTH(Accountability) > 0 OR Accountability IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) + SUM(CASE Respect WHEN LENGTH(Respect) > 0 OR Respect IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) AS Total
    FROM
        MainTable
    GROUP BY
        id
) AS t
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN Total BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN '1-2 Comments'
        WHEN Total BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN '3-4 Comments'
        WHEN Total >= 5 THEN '5+ Comments'
    END
```

Comment: This answer fails as is: `SQL Syntax error`. I will try to debug this later. Some notes: `id` isn't actually a column in `main table` (Whoops). It has a column called `EmployeeNo` that is a unique VARCHAR identifier. I tried just the query `SELECT SUM(CASE Attendance WHEN LENGTH(Attendence) > 0 OR Attendence IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) FROM TBL_NAME;` to see what that returned and likewise got an `SQL Syntax Error`

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I used :

- [Case Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)  - to identify non-empty cells
- [Between](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql) and [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) operator- to get range and row count
- [Unpivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) - to change table-valued expression into another table

  ```
      --- Source
      CREATE TABLE Main
          (
            id INT ,
            attendance VARCHAR(254) ,
            Accountability VARCHAR(254) ,
            Respect VARCHAR(254)
          )

      INSERT  INTO Main
              ( id, attendance, accountability, respect )
      VALUES  ( 1, 'John was always on time', 'John is accountable',
                'John is always respectful' ),
              ( 2, 'Ann never missed a day', 'Ann is very accountable', NULL ),
              ( 3, NULL, NULL, 'Dan was very disrespectful' )


      --- Query
      SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col) id,
              col [range],
              val [count]
      FROM    ( SELECT    SUM(CASE WHEN ctr BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 1
                                   ELSE 0
                              END) [1-2 comments] ,
                          SUM(CASE WHEN ctr BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN 1
                                   ELSE 0
                              END) [3-4 comments] ,
                          SUM(CASE WHEN ctr >= 5 THEN 1
                                   ELSE 0
                              END) [5+ comments]
                FROM      ( SELECT    attendance + Accountability + Respect [ctr]
                            FROM      ( SELECT    CASE WHEN attendance IS NOT NULL
                                                            OR attendance <> ''
                                                       THEN 1
                                                       ELSE 0
                                                  END attendance ,
                                                  CASE WHEN Accountability IS NOT NULL
                                                            OR Accountability <> ''
                                                       THEN 1
                                                       ELSE 0
                                                  END Accountability ,
                                                  CASE WHEN Respect IS NOT NULL
                                                            OR Respect <> '' THEN 1
                                                       ELSE 0
                                                  END Respect
                                        FROM      Main
                                      ) T
                          ) Tmain
              ) TBL UNPIVOT( val FOR col IN ( [1-2 comments], [3-4 comments],
                                              [5+ comments] ) ) UPVT



      DROP TABLE Main
  ```

Result

```
    id                   range               count
    -------------------- ------------------- -----------
    1                    1-2 comments        2
    2                    3-4 comments        1
    3                    5+ comments         0

    (3 row(s) affected)
```